# Forward incoming UDP Packets on Windows Server to client on different interface

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, udp, forwarding

I have the following setup with 2 networks and 3 clients:

- Network A: 192.168.0.0/16
- Network B: 172.16.0.0/12
- Client 1 is connected to Network A (192.168.0.1)
- Client 2 (Windows Server) is connected to Network A (192.168.0.2) and Network B (172.16.0.2)
- Client 3 is connected to Network B (172.16.0.1)

In my setup Client 2 acts as a bridge between the two networks. I can't modify the existing network structure, install any software on Client 1 or 3 or modify the system in any way.

Client 1 is sending UDP Packets to Client 2 (192.168.0.2) to Port 1202. Now I want to forward the Packets to Client 3 (172.16.0.1) to Port 1202. If possible, this should also work in the opposite direction.

The following command using **netsh** should have made this work.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.0.2 listenport=1202 connectaddress=172.16.0.1 connectport=1202
```

However, this only works for **TCP traffic** and not for UDP.

I also found a program called *Simple UDP proxy/pipe* found on [this website](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm), however I could not get it to forward any traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using socat... this program also exists for windows [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unix-utils/files/socat/1.7.3.2/). It takes a little time to read into that tool, but it is really powerful.

[Here](https://mattryall.net/blog/udp-port-forwarding-with-socat) is an explanation how to forward udp traffic with socat.

There exists another way: you could turn your windows server into a network router. [This article](https://rdr-it.com/en/how-to-install-config-windows-server-routing/) explains how. You would need the correct routes installed at client 1 & 3 - so this option is more complicated.